# How to scrape multiple items with JSoup

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to build a program that will import the page "https://rsbuddy.com/exchange", take a .txt file filled with item names, and search and return the name of the item and it's value. I am new to webpage scraping and could use some help!

This is the code I have so far(it's not much...)

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


import java.io.IOException;

public class RuneMerch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document d = Jsoup.connect("https://rsbuddy.com/exchange").timeout(6000).get());
        Elements ele = d.select("")

    }
}
```

Comment: Without JavaScript the website won't even load (DDoS protection by CloudFlare) and the site itself also requires JavaScript. Jsoup doesn't provide JavaScript support, so you might need to look at other options like HtmlUnit or other headless browsers with JavaScript support.

Comment: The Cloudflare DDoS protection also serves as an "Anti-scraping" system of sorts, to prevent exactly this kind of automated extraction. You'll probably have little luck even with a different library.